# website analyzer - SEO data

Tags: seo, sitecore, web-analytics

I'm trying to make a personal web analyzer site using PHP.. I bought a script to get other seo data... Now I want to have the 3 bar-counters like the one shown at the top of this page: http://www.woorank.com/en/www/cnn.com ... The problem is I don't know what these information are and how these are computed.. This is not included on the script I bought as well.. I've already googled alot, and I mean a lot, of websites also but I can't seem to find any site like this.. Can anyone help me with the computation or direct me to sites that show these 3 bar-counter data just for more information?

Comment: The top three bars are nothing but the summation of points given below.

Comment: The site is combination of few sites `http://www.w3.org/QA/Tools/`, `http://www.google.co.in/analytics/`, `http://yslow.org/` are some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am referring to the link you provided.

The three bars at the top.

Successfully passed 32

Room for improvement 5

Errors to fix 8

These are totals of all the individual points listed.

The ones that are successfully passed are marked with a green tick
eg Traffic Estimations

Room for improvement are marked with the orange exclamation mark.
eg Title

Errors to fixed are marked by a red cross
eg IP Canonicalization

To display these bars is a coding issue.

Comment: Oh I see.. thanks for the information.. i thought there's a formula for that.. so do you suggest me counting all those colored ticks instead to get those numbers? is that the only way to so?

Comment: Yes, I wrote a script instead to get those.. Thanks again @yvytty :)

Comment: I posted another question quite similiar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16725854/seo-unreachable-pages .. maybe you can help with that as well.. :)