# SEO - Unreachable pages

Tags: php, wordpress, seo, sitecore, broken-links

I'm trying to make a personal web analyzer site using PHP.. I bought a script to get other seo data... Now I want to have the "Unreachable Pages" evaluation like the one shown at the bottom of this page http://free-website-analysis.net/website-analysis/website-analysis-seo-free/... The problem is I don't know  how these are computed.. This is not included on the script I bought as well.. I've already googled alot, and I mean a lot, of websites also but I can't seem to find any site like this.. Can anyone help me with the computation or direct me to sites that show this information instead?

Comment: What is `Unreachable Pages`?

Comment: @phpNoOb like "Broken links" maybe..

Comment: The only thing shown as the bottom of that page, is a failure of script, there is nothing said unreachable page, and your should also tag the question with wordpress if your site is wordpress

Comment: What? Maybe you're not opening the right page.. There is a table at the bottom of the page.. It's entitled Site Metrics.. I tagged this PHP since that's what I'm using.. Where did you get Wordpress @phpNoOb?

Comment: `Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1 in /home/tratho15/free-website-analysis.net/wp-content/plugins/wassup/wassup.php on line 3954

Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 1 in /home/tratho15/free-website-analysis.net/wp-content/plugins/wassup/wassup.php on line 3954`

Comment: That is what I see at the bottom of the website

Comment: Oh I see.. You're taking the "bottom" so literally.. Sorry.. The table I'm referring to is just a bit above that error.. :)

Comment: Still don't see it. Sorry :)

Comment: Well, basically, it's just showing: 
Unreachable Pages             Good

Comment: and it is a wordpress site right?

Comment: I don't know... All I'm asking is if you know what that means or how to get that evaluation (Good) or if you have other sites similar to that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of each item referenced in the statistics, what it means, and where it comes from.

**Google Page Rank:**
This is Google's proprietary calculation. Google does not provide an API to get the Page Rank but there are tools such as [this](http://code.google.com/p/seostats/) to determine a Page Rank.

**Sitemap:**
The sitemap statistic is simply whether or not the site has a sitemap.xml file. It can be checked by looking for a domain.tld/sitemap.xml file. You can learn about these sitemaps at [sitemaps.org](http://www.sitemaps.org/).

**Robots.txt**
Much like sitemaps, this just checks for a domain.tld/robots.txt file. This is documented at [robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/)

**Page Errors:**
It's hard to tell what page errors are as they could be any number of things.

**Unreachable Pages:** These are [broken links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot). There are tools like [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink) that go through all the links on the page and make sure none return a [404 error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404). You can write a script that turns all the links on the page into an array or object and then use PHP or a command line tool like [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) or [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) to get the headers of the resource (link). Each time you count a 404 error you increment *Unreachable Pages* by one.

**Domain Age & Domain Expiration:** These can be found manually or pragmatically using a [Whois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whois) search.

Hope this helps and good luck!

**EDIT**

There is a tutorial on how to write a broken links checker ("unreachable pages") [here](http://www.innvo.com/c/PHP/1278786173-PHP-broken-link-checker).

Comment: Regarding Unreachable Pages, how will I score that total # whether it's good, average, bad?? Is there a calibration for that?

Comment: Zero unreachable pages is good. Any more than zero is bad. Unreachable pages should not exist and search engines will always punish you for them.